# fstab mount network share with guest

Tags: debian, mount, fstab

when I mount my network share on Debian 9 with command line it goes with success:

```
    mount -t cifs -o guest //Server/Share /mnt/sharefolder
```

But when I add an entry to /etc/fstab:

```
    //Server/Share    /mnt/sharefolder    cifs    guest    0    0
```

There comes the error: failed(Result: exit-code) and status=1/FAILURE

What is my mistake?

Comment: The difference between running `mount.cifs` from console and from `fstab` would be the user. If no `-o username` is given, the current user is used, according to `man mount.cifs`. Now one could expect the option `-o guest` to use a guest user, but the manpage only says "don´t prompt for a password", so I'm not sure about it. I'd try passing the `username` in fstab. There might also be an error message in `dmesg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with these options:

```
    //Server/Share /mnt/sharefolder cifs guest,_netdev,x-systemd.automount 0 0
```